# Where! can I write a code after cmd "py manage.py shell" in Django while creating a database in Django?

Tags: django, sqlite, shell

I'm stuck. I have been creating my first database in Django following a course, but now, I don't understand where to put a code (from filmy.models import Film, Genre*my_film(Film(...))after the above mentioned command "py manage.py shell". What happend, but mainly where! There is something in migrations like "0001_initial.py", however, there is already a code written - shoud I just write the other code below? Thx a lot!

Edited question:

Well, there are files which make the structure of Django like pycache, migrations, static, templates, **init**.py, admin, apps, models, tests. urls, views, db.sqlite3, manage. To which file should I write the above mentioned code (from filmy.models import...).

Lovely!  So it should have been written right in the terminal after the "In [1]" ...
A follow-up problem: There is an error message "DatabaseError: file is not a database". I must have done something wrong, I guess :).

Comment: The `py` command line would be written on the Windows prompt, whereas the Python code should go in your Python file (`manage.py` or something from the local folder which is being `import`ed from `manage.py`). If the previous `py` command is still running, you want to interrupt it, update your code, and run it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those statements sound like the course wants you to create a model via the shell, in which case you'd enter them into the `py manage.py shell` REPL, e.g.

```
$ py manage.py shell
>>> from filmy.models import Film, Genre
>>> g = Genre.objects.create(name="action")
>>> f = Film.objects.create(name="film", genre=g)
>>> exit()
$
```

This would populate your database with a genre and a film, which are then accessible from your web views.

99% of the time you do not want to edit your migration files by hand.

However, not knowing which course this is, it's hard to help further.

Comment: No – that's a binary SQLite file. See above: run `py manage.py shell` and just write the lines there in the interactive shell.